# Cross-platform mobile API for apps that can be listed in all market places

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, mobile, cross-platform

Which cross-platform mobile APIs give apps that can be listed in the major market places? I see PhoneGap generates native apps can be listed in the Android, iOS and Windows markets. What are the other options? I strongly prefer free.

The reason I want native apps is to get the free advertising from being able to list them in the marketplace.

To those who marked the question as off-topic: the selection seems to be very limited. In my searches I've only found PhoneGap which satisfies the criteria (cross-platform, produces native code, free). So it's hard to be opinionated or produce spam comments when the selection is potentially singular. Any suggestions on other options would be welcomed before I commit myself.

Comment: you might like Unity3d http://unity3d.com/

Comment: You can use Xamarin... it's in C#. It's not clear whether the same code can export to all platforms or whether you will have to change the code at least some for other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these ones out:

[Icenium](http://www.icenium.com/)

[Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-platform/)

I personally prefer phonegap though.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! It looks like there's not that many resources out there and phonegap seems to be the only free one.

Comment: Icenium uses Cordova as its base, but significantly improves user experience in setting up the project and building. Moreover it supports custom plugins, something that phonegap build does not offer yet. If you would be putting a price tag on your app, then the monthly subscription is negligible.